# convex optimisation formulation of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm, convex, lagrange-multipliers

I am currently learning about Support Vector Machine's (SVM) from the [CS229 Stanford Class](http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2019/cs229-notes3.pdf). In page 16 of the notes, they transformed
$$max_{\hat{\gamma}, w, b} \frac{\hat{\gamma}}{||w||} \\
s.t \,\,\,y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)}+b) \geq \hat{\gamma}, \,\, i = 1,....n
$$
into
$$
min_{w,b} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 \\
s.t \,\,\,y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)}+b) \geq 1, \,\, i = 1,....n
$$
I have a few questions relating to this transformation which I don't really understand from the notes.

1. Why can they set $\hat{\gamma} = 1$? This was the crux of why they could perform the transformation
2. They mentioned that the objective function for the first equation is non - convex. I am not familiar with convex optimisation. Is it because of the variable $\hat{\gamma}$ that makes it non-convex. But why is that so ?

Regarding the first question, the notes explained it in this manner

> Let’s keep going. Recall our earlier discussion that we can add an arbitrary scaling constraint on w and b without changing anything. This is the key idea we’ll use now. We will introduce the scaling constraint that the functional margin of w, b with respect to the training set must be 1: